# Modelling tangent bundles on affine spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

Let $(A,V)$ be an affine space over a finite dimensional real vector space $V$. $A$ is homeomorphic to $V$, and thus a topological manifold. It is also easily equipped with a smooth structure to make it a smooth manifold. Also, its tangent bundle is trivial and can be identified as $A\times V$. A differentiable map $f:A\to B$ between affine spaces $(A,V),~(B,W)$ then induces a map
$$\begin{align}\mathrm df:&A\times V\to B\times V,\\
&(P,v)\mapsto(f(P),\mathrm df_P(v)).
\end{align}$$
This is really the trivial case of the usual differential $\mathrm df:TM\to TN$ of a function between manifolds $M,N$. But it's slightly better than the seemingly even more trivial case of the differential of a function between vector spaces because affine spaces already come equipped with their own custom made tangent spaces and associated trivial tangent bundle.

So my question is: could we model the tangent bundle on this trivial tangent bundle over an affine space, instead of constructing tangent spaces out of thin air (or maybe thick air, but the fact that we have several different standard constructions makes it seem a bit unnatural) and gluing them together to get the tangent bundle? Something along the lines of: a tangent bundle $TM$ is a vector bundle $TM\to M$ whose local trivializations are homeomorphic to $U\times V$, where $U$ is an open subset of an affine space over $V$, and whose coordinate changes are induced by the differential of the coordinate changes of $M$, that is, if $\phi$ is a coordinate change of $M$, then $(\phi,\mathrm d\phi)$ is a coordinate change of $TM$.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: If we choose the affine spaces to be $\mathbb{R}^n$, isn't this just the normal construction of the tangent bundle via coordinate charts?

Comment: @Max: I don't mean to introduce a new standard. More like trying to understand tangent bundles from an additional perspective.

Comment: @Kajelad: Now that you say it that way, it looks like it. I was only considering the construction of the tangent bundle constructed from tangent spaces, but that's not the only standard way. The reverse approach does look very similar to what I tried to do.